# Google Chrome Invalidating Cookies

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies, google-location-services

I use a extension for python called [LocationSharingLib](https://github.com/costastf/locationsharinglib/) that can perform automation with specific locations shared with my google account. The process is, you export your Google Cookies to a file and use this as input for the library

```
from locationsharinglib import Service

cookies_file = 'cookies.txt'
google_email = '<your google username>@gmail.com'

service = Service(cookies_file=cookies_file, authenticating_account=google_email)

for person in service.get_all_people():
    print(person)
```

Periodically, I have to fetch new Google cookies and update the cookies.txt file (like once every few weeks). However I have noticed recently that whenever my Chrome is open on my home computer, the session becomes invalidated after 15-20 minutes (I am not logging out of Google).

Is there anyway to check why the cookie is becoming invalidated so soon? I have narrowed down the issue that something with Chrome running is causing the cookie to become invalidated. I turned off all sync components but it seems like a core Chrome function is invalidating the cookies.